# WP Получить id всех постов определенного автора

Tags: массивы, wordpress

Подскажите, есть ли готовые методы для получения всех опубликованных постов автора в цикле?
*Желательно в виде массива из id этих постов.

Comment: См шаблон autor.php в любой нормальной теме.  А так WP_Query наше всё.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот код получения массива id постов автора `black_star`:

```php
$args = [
    'author_name'    => 'black_star',
    'posts_per_page' => - 1,
    'fields'         => 'ids',
];

$author_post_ids = get_posts( $args );
```

Comment: Спасибо, у меня вопрос, если необходимо по id автора собирать этот массив из опубликованых постов? Попробовал вместо `'author_name'    => 'black_star', ` ---> поставить ` 'author_id'    => 1,  'post_type'   => 'post', `  то массивы почему-то разные выдает. С чем это может быть связано?

Comment: Разные по сравнению с чем? author_name = black_star может иметь другой id, не 1. `'post_type' => 'post'` вообще смысла не имеет, всё по умолчанию. Гуглим `wp-kama get_posts`, видим, что параметры все те же, что для WP_Query, гуглим `wp-kama WP_Query` и изучаем, какие параметры доступны.

Comment: Всё понял свой косяк, нету такого аргумента `'author_id`, есть `'author'`  странно, что оно вообще какой-то массив выдавало... https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_posts/ Спасибо.